# typescript: sending an object field conditionally

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to have an optional field on object.  If the `state` variable equals `active`, I want to have `data.fields` equal to `show`.  If `state` does not equal `active`, I don't want `terms` to even be part of the `data` object.  The way I have below is my workaround but `null` still sends which I don't want.

```
let state = 'active';

let data = {
   name: "John",
   age: 22,
   terms: state === 'active' ? 'show' : null
}

axios.post(url, data);
```

Is a proper alternative this:

```
let state = 'active';

let data = {
   name: "John",
   age: 22,
}

if (this.state === 'active') {
   data.terms = 'show';
}

axios.post(url, data);
```

Comment: later is proper than above. it's possible to expand object field by `object.field = value`

Comment: I just realized I get an error in my console when I do that saying `"property terms does not exist on { name: "john", age: 22}"`. I am also using typescript, which I did not specify originally...will update the question to indicate that

Comment: Did you check `this.state === 'active'` is `true`?